# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment with btn button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, button, referenceerror

A link via bootstrap button shall be displayed in the basic entry only if a premium entry was booked. This shall be realized within the portal module of the Worldsoft CMS.

The first solution works good in Chrome, IE, etc. but not in Firefox. Nothing happens there if I click on the button. I think, it is not valid to have an `<a>` inside a `<button>`.
First I will show the code with the given `<wstag>` and afterwards I show you what will be made of it:

```
<---First solution works good (Code with tags):------------------------->
<script type='text/javascript'>
detailbutton();
function detailbutton() {  
    var tiendadetails = ('<wstag class="wsTag" id="306" type="ddbf_137" 
widget="checkbox">Portal Field :: Tienda-Details</wstag>');
    if (tiendadetails == 'Premium-Eintrag') 
         { document.write("<button class='btn btn-warning'>" + "<wstag 
class="wsTag" id="290" type="PORTALS_MORE" widget="link">" + "Portals :: 
Mehr..." + "</wstag>" + "</button>"); } 
    else { document.write('<p style="color: #ff0000;">only basic entry, 
no further information</p>'); }
}
</script>

<---First solution (Code looks resolved like this):--------------------->
<script type='text/javascript'>
detailbutton();
function detailbutton() {  
    var tiendadetails = ('Premium-Eintrag');
    if (tiendadetails == 'Premium-Eintrag') 
        { document.write("<button class='btn btn-warning'>" + "<a 
href='/portal/9/68/tiendassantanyi/cult?     
portal_id=16&peid=9&q=&next=22,30,e&previous=s&qid=3cp8rbc8erv1klro299d02
mdn4&p=&location_id=68' >Premium Entry: Click here for important details! 
</a>" + "</button>"); } 
    else { document.write('<p style="color: #ff0000;">only basic entry, 
no further information</p>'); }
}
</script>
```

My new solution instead get the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

(in line "var premium ...")

```
<!---------------New Script Button for Premium-Eintrag------------------>
<script type='text/javascript'>
premium();
function premium() { 
    var premium = ('<wstag class="wsTag" id="290" type="PORTALS_MORE" 
widget="link">Portals :: Mehr...</wstag>'); 
}
detailbutton();
function detailbutton() {
    var tiendadetails = ('<wstag class="wsTag" id="306" type="ddbf_137" 
widget="checkbox">Portal Field :: Tienda-Details</wstag>');
    if (tiendadetails == 'Premium-Eintrag')
        { document.write('<button class="btn btn-warning" id="premium"> 
</button>'); } 
    else { document.write('<p style="color: #ff0000;">only basic entry, 
no further information</p>'); }
}
</script>

<!----------------------looks resolved like this------------------------>
<script type="text/javascript">
premium();
function premium(){ 
var premium = ('<a href='/portal/9/68/tiendassantanyi/cult? 
portal_id=16&peid=9&q=&next=22,30,e&previous=s&qid=3cp8rbc8erv1klro299d02
mdn4&p=&location_id=68' >Premium Entry: Click here for important details! 
</a>'); 
}
detailbutton();
function detailbutton(){
    var tiendadetails = ('Premium-Eintrag');
    if (tiendadetails == 'Premium-Eintrag')
        { document.write('<button class="btn btn-warning" id="premium"> 
</button>'); } 
    else { document.write('<p style="color: #ff0000;">only basic entry, 
no further information</p>'); }
}
</script>
```

I don't find my mistake!? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Take care with your simple or double quotes in `var premium`

Use

`var premium = ('<a href="your url" >Premium Entry: Click here for important details! 
</a>');`

instead of

`var premium = ('<a href='your url' >Premium Entry: Click here for important details! 
</a>');`

Comment: Hello Romain B.  I don't see any differens between 'Use' and 'instead of' !?

Comment: When you start a string with single quotes, anything you do inside of these quotes that would typically need to be wrapped in quotes needs to use double quotes, or the string will end. In the first example, the "inside" quotes are double quotes to prevent the string from ending. Romain B.'s answer is correct.

Comment: Once more: Thanks to @Romain and @MutualDesigns! I overlooked that.
I changed it, but the button is not displayed as it should be. 
The code is located on the [link](page:http://aprico24.cms4all.info/modules/portals/search.php?location_id=68&portal_id=16&mode=sr&qid=di3h8nk4ebk0d4fe5qrttv6ct7). See screenshot right / wrong at the end of the page.

Comment: Okay I found one mistake, but nothing happens there if I click on the first button . . .!?

Comment: The first button does'nt work at all and the second button works correctly but not in Firefox  (both without an error message).

Comment: @Romain: Your reference **does not work*! (see above)  - or is something else wrong? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: @MutualDesigns: Your reference **does not work**! (see above)  - or is something else wrong? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: You are using buttons with anchor links inside of them. This isn't best practice. Just use anchor links and style them with bootstrap classes. https://codepen.io/mutualdesigns/pen/KJaLKx

Comment: @MutalDesigns: Thanks for you help, but I'm sorry: **this is not possible for me**, because the link will be generated by <wstag class="wsTag" id="290". . . > which includes already the attribute <a href ...>. Code see above under "New Script Button for Premium-Eintrag" and convertet "looks resolved like this". Or should I do also something else in addition?

Comment: I will try it with the ".slice-method.